# Best way to import a website into a Visual Sourcesafe 2005 Database

Tags: import, visual-sourcesafe

What is the best way to import a website into a Visual Sourcesafe 2005 database?

I tried opening a the VSS database and drag-n-drop the folder but it started prompting me for a comment on each folder. Is there a better way or someway to have it only ask onces for any files or folders that are being processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your using ASP.NET for your website, if not Im sorry but you dont specify in your question. There is an [MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972977.aspx#vssstarttofinish_topic4) describing how to work with ASP.NET websites in VSS, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio (03/05/08) with the VSS source control plug-in installed, it's pretty easy to right-click on an existing solution or project and choose "Add X to SourceSafe".